# Challenge of payment for earnest money

Tags: property

I purchased a home and paid the agreed earnest money. Living and traveling between two cities, at the time, I don't remember how the money was paid (wire, cashier's check, money order) but all parties (including buyer, seller, both representing realtors and both escrow attorneys) agreed that the earnest money was paid. The house closed without event and the closing documents confirmed earnest money was paid.

Fourteen months later the seller's real estate agent is claiming the earnest money was never paid. Seller's agent is suing me for failure to pay earnest money and demanding proof of payment. A debt collector is representing the plaintiff and there has been no proof presented for "failure to pay".

Are the closing documents sufficient proof? If not, what would be?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You will need to remember how you paid the earnest money and find/"undust" evidence of parties' admission that you paid it. You might be the target of a scam and malicious prosecution, but it is hard to give you a more precise hint on how to debunk it without you recalling those details.

Comment: Uncontested closing documents confirming payment is the admission I have of payment.

Comment: What jurisdiction is this in? Country, and if the US, state, please.

Comment: Unless you paid cash, the transaction will be on your bank statement. Did you check it?

Comment: which jurisdiction are you in? does the closing document contain a clause that contains something akin to "payments were made"/"are to be made"?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Tennessee, USA

Answer (score 1):

### Why are you providing proof that you paid?

They are the ones claiming you owe them money so they are the ones that need to prove that you do. You don't need to prove that you don't.

Comment: depends on jurisdiction. Providing a proof that you paid is enough grounds to destroy their claims and showing they had not the due diligence.